# Why am I having node issues with my AVL tree in Java?

Tags: java, tree

The current project I am working on is developing a AVL tree class. I'm not the most brilliant programmer, but I do have a pretty good idea of how this structure is supposed to work. My first test case was a RL imbalance, and my tree was able to restructure properly. However, for my next test case for a LL imbalance, something strange is happening. My code correctly identifies the imbalance, it seems to correctly rotate, but for the final tree, the nodes added before balancing become removed and the tree reverts back to the state it was before nodes are added. Its a bit of a weird issue to explain so of course I will provide my code. It's entirely possible I'm just making a silly mistake somewhere, but thats where a fresh set of eyes would really help. Also, if anyone has any suggestions to improve my coding practice that would be appreciated, thanks!

This class is part of a library of data structures I have been developing for a course of mine. I will post just the code for this class, but if anyone needs the interfaces/superclasses, I can provide them.

```
package lib280.tree;

public class AVLTree280<I extends Comparable<? super I>> extends OrderedSimpleTree280<I>{



protected AVLNode280<I> AVLNode280RootLeftChild(){
    return (AVLNode280<I>) this.rootNode().leftNode();
}

protected AVLNode280<I> AVLNode280Root(){
    return (AVLNode280<I>) this.rootNode();
}

protected AVLNode280<I> AVLNode280RootRightChild(){
    return (AVLNode280<I>) this.rootNode().rightNode();
}

protected AVLNode280<I> createNewNode(I x){
    return new AVLNode280<I>(x);
}

public AVLTree280<I> rootLeftSubtree(){
    return (AVLTree280<I>) super.rootLeftSubtree();
}

public AVLTree280<I> rootRightSubtree(){
    return (AVLTree280<I>) super.rootRightSubtree();
}



/** Insert x into the tree. <br>
Analysis : Time = O(log n) worst case, where **/
public void insert(I x,AVLTree280<I> tree)
{
    if (tree.isEmpty()){
        tree.rootNode = createNewNode(x);
    }
    else if (x.compareTo(tree.rootItem()) < 0)
    {
        if(tree.rootNode().leftNode()==null) tree.rootNode().leftNode=createNewNode(x);

        else{
            insert(x,tree.rootLeftSubtree());
        }

        tree.AVLNode280Root().setLeftSubTreeHeight((Math.max(tree.AVLNode280RootLeftChild().getRightSubTreeHeight(), tree.AVLNode280RootLeftChild().getLeftSubTreeHeight()))+1);

    }

    else{

        if(tree.rootNode().rightNode()==null) tree.rootNode().rightNode=createNewNode(x);

        else{
            insert(x,tree.rootRightSubtree());
        }

        tree.AVLNode280Root().setRightSubTreeHeight((Math.max(tree.AVLNode280RootRightChild().getLeftSubTreeHeight(), tree.AVLNode280RootRightChild().getRightSubTreeHeight()))+1);
    }

    restoreAVLProperty(tree);
}


protected int balancingFactor(AVLTree280<I> tree){
    return tree.AVLNode280Root().getLeftSubTreeHeight()-tree.AVLNode280Root().getRightSubTreeHeight();
}


protected void restoreAVLProperty(AVLTree280<I> tree){
    if (balancingFactor(tree) == 2) { //left side
        if (balancingFactor(tree.rootLeftSubtree()) == -1) { //reduce left right imbalance to left left
            tree.rootNode().leftNode=rotateLeft(tree.AVLNode280RootLeftChild());
        }

        tree.rootNode=rotateRight(tree.AVLNode280Root());// fix left left imbalance
        System.out.println("The tree root node at this point is: " +tree.rootNode().toString());
    } 
    else if(balancingFactor(tree)==-2){ // right side
        if (balancingFactor(tree.rootRightSubtree()) == 1) { //reduce right left imbalance to right right
                    tree.rootNode().rightNode=rotateRight(tree.AVLNode280RootRightChild()); 
                }

        tree.rootNode=rotateLeft(tree.AVLNode280Root()); //fix right right imbalance
    }
    else{

    }
}

protected AVLNode280<I> rotateLeft(AVLNode280<I> node){
    AVLNode280<I> holder,holder2;
    holder=(AVLNode280<I>) node.rightNode();
    node.setRightNode(holder.leftNode());
    holder.setLeftNode(node);

    holder2 = (AVLNode280<I>) node.rightNode();
    if(holder2!=null){
        node.setRightSubTreeHeight(Math.max(holder2.getLeftSubTreeHeight(),holder2.getRightSubTreeHeight())+1);
    }
    else{
        node.setRightSubTreeHeight(0);
    }

    holder2 = (AVLNode280<I>) node.leftNode();
    if(holder2!=null){
        node.setLeftSubTreeHeight(Math.max(holder2.getLeftSubTreeHeight(),holder2.getRightSubTreeHeight())+1);
    }
    else{
        node.setLeftSubTreeHeight(0);
    }

    holder2=(AVLNode280<I>) holder.rightNode();
    if(holder2!=null){
        holder.setRightSubTreeHeight(Math.max(holder2.getLeftSubTreeHeight(),holder2.getRightSubTreeHeight())+1);
    }
    else{
        holder.setRightSubTreeHeight(0);
    }

    holder.setLeftSubTreeHeight(Math.max(node.getLeftSubTreeHeight(),node.getRightSubTreeHeight())+1);

    return holder;
} 

protected AVLNode280<I> rotateRight(AVLNode280<I> node){
    AVLNode280<I> holder,holder2;
    holder=(AVLNode280<I>) node.leftNode();
    node.setLeftNode(holder.rightNode());
    holder.setRightNode(node);

    holder2 = (AVLNode280<I>) node.leftNode();
    if(holder2!=null){
        node.setLeftSubTreeHeight(Math.max(holder2.getLeftSubTreeHeight(),holder2.getRightSubTreeHeight())+1);
    }
    else{
        node.setLeftSubTreeHeight(0);
    }

    holder2 = (AVLNode280<I>) node.rightNode();
    if(holder2!=null){
        node.setRightSubTreeHeight(Math.max(holder2.getLeftSubTreeHeight(),holder2.getRightSubTreeHeight())+1);
    }
    else{
        node.setRightSubTreeHeight(0);
    }

    holder2=(AVLNode280<I>) holder.leftNode();
    if(holder2!=null){
        holder.setLeftSubTreeHeight(Math.max(holder2.getLeftSubTreeHeight(),holder2.getRightSubTreeHeight())+1);}
    else{
        holder.setLeftSubTreeHeight(0);
    }

    holder2=(AVLNode280<I>) holder.rightNode();
    if(holder2!=null){
    holder.setRightSubTreeHeight(Math.max(node.getLeftSubTreeHeight(),node.getRightSubTreeHeight())+1);
    }
    else{
        holder.setRightSubTreeHeight(0);
    }

    System.out.println("Holder at this point is: " +holder.toString());
    return holder;
}

public void printTreeHeights(AVLNode280<I> node){
    if(node==null) return;
    System.out.println("left: "+ Integer.toString(node.getLeftSubTreeHeight())+" , "+ "right: "+ Integer.toString(node.getRightSubTreeHeight())+"\n");
    printTreeHeights((AVLNode280<I>)node.leftNode());
    printTreeHeights((AVLNode280<I>)node.rightNode());
        }


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    AVLTree280<Integer> testAVL=new AVLTree280<Integer>();

    System.out.println("Test for RL imbalance");
    testAVL.insert(5, testAVL);
    //System.out.println(testAVL.toString());
    testAVL.insert(10, testAVL);
//  System.out.println(testAVL.toString());
    testAVL.insert(6,testAVL);
    //System.out.println(testAVL.toString());
//  testAVL.printTreeHeights(testAVL.AVLNode280Root());
    System.out.println("-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-_-");

    System.out.println("Test for LL imbalance");
    testAVL.insert(1,testAVL);
    System.out.println(testAVL.toString());
    //testAVL.printTreeHeights(testAVL.AVLNode280Root());
    testAVL.insert(0,testAVL);
    //testAVL.printTreeHeights(testAVL.AVLNode280Root());
    System.out.println(testAVL.toString());
}
```

}

The output of the first case with level order traversal is 6, 5, 10

the next case goes 6,5,10,1 using level order traversal. After the 0 is inserted and rebalanced the tree goes back to 6,5,10. This is strange because I have a statement that prints the value to be returned after a re-balance

Holder at this point is: 1
The tree root node at this point is: 1

Those two statements show that the LL re-balance happens but doesnt get updated correctly.